# How to set HMR on ng build --watch and reload URL automatically?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to set HOT RELOAD on the ng build --watch. I have tried so many ways to put the watch. It recognizes too. But, I am unable to reload the URL with it. I need to manually reload the URL.

Could anyone please help with the same?

For more information, I would like to implement on the basic setup of the Angular project.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new mydreamapp
cd my-dream-app
ng build --watch
```

Here is the angular.json for the reference

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "mydreamapp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/mydreamapp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mydreamapp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "mydreamapp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mydreamapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "mydreamapp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "mydreamapp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "mydreamapp"
}
```

Comment: Can you update your main.ts & other configuration code to the question which could help spot the issue

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid I have updated it. Please have a look

Comment: Whats the values of 'outputPath' under options array in angular.json

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid Please check angular.json

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to find from the angular documentation that we need to add output path along with the watch command.

The same issue is discussed in this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2511

Since your output folder mentioned in angular.json is 'dist', use the command as below.

```
ng build --output-path dist --watch
```

You can add the same command under the script section of package json for easiness.

Comment: It is not working for me. How can I check locally?